# Where can I find the European equivalents ETFs from a USD superdiversified 10 ETFs portfolio

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, portfolio, etf, portfolio-selection

I have been using this superdiversified 10 ETFs portfolio.
To lower the risk it's composed from stocks and bonds across the globe and includes some commodities.
Being in USD currency and the Euro being on the rise I wanted to find equivalents ETFs (tracking the same indexes) in Euros.
Where could I find the equivalents ETFs I could buy in Europe (ideally from France) ?

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| ticker | Exchange-traded Fund                             | Percent (%) |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| BWX    | SPDR Bloomberg Barclays Intl Treasury Bond       |  13         |
| EMLC   | VanEck Vectors JP Morgan Emer Mkts Loc Curr Bond |  10         |
| BND    | Vanguard Total Bond Market                       |   9         |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| IAU    | iShares Gold Trust                               |  11         |
| DBC    | PowerShares DB Commodity Tracking                |   5         |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| VEU    | Vanguard FTSE All-World ex-U.S.                  |  17         |
| VWO    | Vanguard FTSE Emerging Markets Index             |  14         |
| VNQI   | Vanguard Global ex-U.S. Real Estate              |   4         |
| VNQ    | Vanguard REIT                                    |   6         |
| VTI    | Vanguard Total Stock Market                      |  11         |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Composite Portfolio                                       | 100         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Very nice portfolio, but both VEU and VWO include Emerging Markets. Is that intentional? Maybe you meant VEA instead of VEU.

Comment: Yes this is intentional

Comment: This question is identical to https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/84395/where-can-i-find-the-european-equivalent-etfs-from-a-usd-superdiversified-10-etf and https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=226559

Answer (score 1):

You can find the tracked indices on bloomberg. Just open the corresponding ticker and type comp or get the field FUND_BENCHMARK_PRIM if you dont know it already.

There are several pages such as etfdb.com or morningstar for example where you can search ETFs by benchmark. Just pick your benchmark and choose an ETF from the list that is suitable for your needs.

You will need to make small concessions though I guess. For some of these will not have a widely accepted benchmark and there wont be other suitable products.

The DBC is such a case. Since it "tracks" a proprietary index, there will not be a like for like replacement. (probably you can buy this one in France anyway, but you see my point)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, this portfolio is well diversified across the world, so I would not worry about currency risk unduly. However, if you are not happy with the currency exposure it gives you, you could change it by using a "currency overlay", that is add currency futures or forwards to bring the exposure to whatever you wish.